# i never used ko.applyBindings before yet there is an error that is saying that i apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I apply it only once (at least i think so). And i get this error message

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Project is MVC 5 and webAPI 2.

Here is the simplified code:

This is simplified layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/knockout")<!--knockout mapping also included here-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jqueryval")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

contact controller view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Templates/_ContactList.cshtml")<!--partial view - code is given below --> 
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/viewmodel/contact")<!--js contact view model- code is given below-->
}
```

contact list partial view:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" data-bind="visible: contacts().length > 0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
    <tr data-bind="attr: { 'id': ID }">
        <td data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Address"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: City"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

js contact view model:

```
var contactVM = function () {
    //api url
    var url = "/api/contact";
    var self = this;
    // list of contacts
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

    // single contact
    self.contact = ko.observable('');

    //contact properties
    self.ID = ko.observable('');
    self.Name = ko.observable('');
    self.Address = ko.observable('');
    self.City = ko.observable('');

    $('.ajax-loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.contacts(data);
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    }).always(function () {
        $('.ajax-loading').hide();
    });
};
$(window).load(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new contactVM());
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never apply the bindings via the object itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/kPDW9/

Here, there is also a division between the contact model and the contacts themselves.

```
var Contact = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Address = ko.observable(data.Address);
    self.City = ko.observable(data.City);
}

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    // list of contacts
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

In addition, for the example, the ajax call is also outside of the view model to separate the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Call `ko.applyBindings` from $(document).ready(...) instead of $(window).load(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can also move you apply bindings to inside the model. Like this:

```
 var contactVM = function () {
    //api url
    var url = "/api/contact";
    var self = this;
    // list of contacts
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

    // single contact
    self.contact = ko.observable('');

    //contact properties
    self.ID = ko.observable('');
    self.Name = ko.observable('');
    self.Address = ko.observable('');
    self.City = ko.observable('');

    $('.ajax-loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.contacts(data);
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    }).always(function () {
        $('.ajax-loading').hide();
    });

    ko.applyBindings(self);
};
$(window).load(function () {
    var viewModel = new contactVM();
});
```